# SSRS - common expressions DATE&TIME?

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS report based of a table that have [timestamp] and [status] field .
i am trying to count hourly  TIMESTAMP based of sample below .
ON MY TABLE I WONT TO COUNT HOURLY TIMESTAMP  EXCLUDING DATE
ONE FIELD [6A-7A] 2ND -[8A-9A] ?

[enter image description here]
[image: 1]
which Common function expression should i manipulate in SSRS to get results .

```
timestamp                   STATUS
1/19/2010   6:04:41 AM       PAY
04/19/2010  7:04:41 AM      DENY
1/19/2010   8:04:41 AM      PEND
02/19/2010  1:04:41 PM      ADJU
1/19/2010   4:04:41 PM      PAY
10/22/2010  7:04:41 PM       PAY
```

Comment: FYI-i only wont count on hourly bases  [7am-8am ] ,  [8am-9am]

Comment: use a matrix and add a column group, group this using an expression such as `=HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Group By the HOUR to get the hour part.

```
=HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)
```

For the displayed value you could use the FORMAT function to get the hour and AM/PM *period* (figuring out that term was a can of worms).

```
=FORMAT(Fields!timestamp.Value, "ht") & " - " & FORMAT(DateAdd("h", 1, NOW), "ht")
```

The *h* is for hour and the *t* is for the first part of the AM or PM period. *tt* would be used to show AM or PM.

If you only want to show hours 8 and 9, you would add a filter expression to the Column Grouping.

```
=HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)
```

> Datatype: **Integer**
>
> Operator: **BETWEEN**
>
> Values:   **8** **9**

Comment: okay[ =HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)] would give me hourly count . how about specific time of the day only example [8am-9am ]

Comment: Thank you Guys !!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your suggestion was helpful .
in case someone needed an answer this worked for me .
below expression will get time hourly report [7a-8a],[8a-9a]...ETC to be specific

=SUM(IIF(HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)= 7,1,0)) +SUM(IIF(HOUR(Fields!timestamp.Value)= 8,1,0))